# line-height in stylesheet of iTextSharp HTMLWorker

Tags: c#, itext

We have a method for translating html from tynimce to pdf:

```
private void SetStyle(Document document, string html, float fountSize)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(html))
        {
            StyleSheet styles = new StyleSheet();
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.COLOR, "#ffffff");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FONTFAMILY, "Arial Unicode MS");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.SIZE, Convert.ToString(fountSize) + "pt");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.LINEHEIGHT, Convert.ToString(fountSize) + "pt");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.P, HtmlTags.LINEHEIGHT, Convert.ToString(fountSize) + "pt");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.SPAN, HtmlTags.LINEHEIGHT, Convert.ToString(fountSize) + "pt");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.A, HtmlTags.COLOR, "#00ADEF");
            styles.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
            List<IElement> objects = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
                new StringReader(html), styles);
            foreach (IElement element in objects)
            {
                document.Add(element);
            }
        }
    }
```

But HtmlTags.LINEHEIGHT does not work, how to set the line-height correctly?

Comment: Please post the code where you are calling the `SetStyle` function ans also the contents of the parameter that you passing.

Comment: SetStyle(document, newHtml, 9f); var newHtml = <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. ante,&nbsp;</p>

Comment: What is `document` and `newHtml`?

Comment: document - iTextSharp.Documentvar newHtml = <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. ante,&nbsp;</p>

Comment: As documented in many places `HTMLWorker` is no longer supported. Version 5 of iText replaced `HTMLWorker` with XML Worker; iText 7 replaced XML Worker with the pdfHTML add-on. The use of `HTMLWorker` is not encouraged since it is no longer supported.